# Wow.js not working in server

Tags: javascript, jquery, wow.js

In am using wow.js to animate element on scroll. It works great in local but when I uploaded to server, the animated class is called before scrolling (with page loads). 
[Click here](http://46.101.217.30/vezio/landing/how-it-works.html)

to see it live.
[image]

Answer (score 0):

I think it worked locally because the page assets above the gif loaded faster than in the web. When I open the page, the `wow` used `div` is loading with "animated" class before I scroll for it (It happened because the wow `div` was visible while the header page assets was loading).

The `wow.js` is used to animate some HTML element on scroll and not to control the gif animation state but it works as you want because the `wow` apply `visibility: visible` in element after its `div` is visible.

You can start the animation of the gif when its visible at the page if you show the image only when you scroll, controlling its visibility state (loading with image visibility hidden and then changing it to visible).

You can also start the gif animation when scrolling if you use something like [this plugin](http://www.appelsiini.net/projects/lazyload) to "lazy load" the image. "Lazy load" plugin will load the image when it is going to be visible in the window.